# example sample of lexical analyzer in c#

Tags: c#

i want to use some built in lexical analyzer and parser, i need some examples or samples demonstaring the use.

any one has use any lexical analyzer in C#???

can any one share the sample and code how to use that.

i didnt find many ANTLR and lex 
but i cant find any examples or tutorial.

please let me know if any one has used any such thing.

Answer (score 5):

The Lucene.NET Text Analyzer  looks quite promising, and is probably something more along the lines of what you are looking for:

[Lucene Text Analyzer - C# | CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/lucene_analysis.aspx)

Here is an HTML Lexical Analyzer written in C#, might help get you pointed in the right direction.

[HTML Lexical Analyzer - C# | CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/AfterWork_HTML_Parser.aspx)

Finally, here is a blog by Omer van Kloeten on the design of Lexical Analyzers, in case you decide to work on your own:

[Designing a Lexical Analyzer | Omer van Kloeten's Blog](https://omervk.wordpress.com/2004/07/13/designing-the-lexical-analyzer/)

Comment: It looks like this is the updated link for [Designing a Lexical Analyzer](https://omervk.wordpress.com/2004/07/13/designing-the-lexical-analyzer/) as the original no longer works.