# Convert a string to an operator?

Tags: c#, .net, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a string math evaluator in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355062/is-there-a-string-math-evaluator-in-net)

Is there a way to convert the operator code without doing a check for `"+", "-", "*", "/"` and then passing the value?

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string operator = "+";
            int inputOne = 2;
            int inputTwo = 5;

            Console.WriteLine(Result(inputOne, inputTwo, operator));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        public static string Result(int one, int two, string computeOperator)
        {
            if (computeOperator == "+")
            {
                return (one + two).ToString();
            }

            if (computeOperator == "-")
            {
                return (one - two).ToString();
            }

            //and so on...

            return "0";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Find a good mathematical expression parser.

Comment: you could pass a delegate, such as `Func<int, int, int>`.

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355062/is-there-a-string-math-evaluator-in-net

Comment: You are going to end up implementing a fully-working calculator with two stacks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**, not the way you appear to be wanting to. A [string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), by definition, cannot be converted into an operator.

Comment: I don't know about that.  There are several possible approaches in the link that @Dan Andrews posted above.

Comment: @DavidStratton under the hood, those possible approaches are doing a string comparison similar to the way the OP is doing. They wouldn't be converting a string literal to an operator.

Comment: You're right.  I guess I was just looking at the end result - "can he achieve what he wanted (taking a string that is clearly a mathematicval expresssion and calculating it) by taking a different approach", not "can he achieve what he wants using the approach he is specifically asking about".  But you are right in pointing out that the approach he was asking about will not work.  Sometimes I focus so much on the end result I forget to pay attention on how to get there.  Something I need to improve upon at times.  I bet I'd be a better coder if I did pay more attention to how I get there.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is similar to [example sample of lexical analyzer in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598288/example-sample-of-lexical-analyzer-in-c-sharp). You can try to use one of those lexical analyzers but unless you're going to be parsing a lot of text, it might not be worth it.

For reference, this is probably the most relevant of the link from that answer...

[Lucene Text Analyzer - C# | CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/lucene_analysis.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Simply **NO**. 
But you can do calculation using [Eval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe.aspx)